# How to query contents(posts/videos) of people, a user follows with Django ORM when the user's details and following list is in separate database

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

Hey guys I recently starting working on a project where there are two different databases for storing user information and all the posted contents. I want to fetch and show, the contents posted by users who are in current user's following list.

If this was in a single database, I could use a join statement like this,

```
current_user = self.request.user.id
following_ids = self.request.user.following.values_list('id',flat=True)
posts = Content.objects.filter(Q(user_id__in=following_ids) | Q(user__id=current_user))
```

but since we use two different databases, how can I execute a similar query to show the contents.

Please do help.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a [router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers) already defined? If so you can do something like `Content.objects.using('myotherdb').filter(Q(user_id__in=following_ids) | Q(user__id=current_user.id))`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Yes, router is defined. I will check this out and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a [**`router`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers), you can just [use that in your queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset) to specify which db you want it to use so:

```
Content.objects.using('myotherdb').filter(
    Q(user_id__in=following_ids) | Q(user__id=current_user.id)
)
```